# Understanding Stokes' theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, definition, stokes-theorem

I don't know a lot about differentials and boundaries, so it may be out of my grasp, but is there perhaps a simple way of understanding the Stokes' theorem for the FTC?

> $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x =
> \int_{[a,b]} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x =
> \int_{[a,b]} \mathrm{d}F(x) =
> \int_{\partial[a,b]} F(x)
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle
> \neq \int_{\{a,b\}}F(x) = F(a)+F(b)
> \\\displaystyle \overset{?}{=} \int_{(*)}F(x) = -F(a)+F(b)
> \end{array}\right.\\$

So I don't really understand why $\partial[a,b] \neq \{a,b\}$, and what the blank $(*)$ is supposed to be. So I guess the question is, what are the prerequisites to understand that part?

Comment: As a set $\partial [a,b] = \{a,b\}$ but this does *not* account for orientations, and integrals are sensitive to orientations of their domain.

Comment: Also when you write FTA I think you mean FTC

Comment: @john sorry for the tyop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general Stokes' theorem $∫_M dω = ∫_{∂M} ω$, $M$ is an *oriented* manifold with boundary, and $∂M$ is the boundary with a particular induced orientation.  In the case of $M = [a,b]$ the usual orientation is "going left to right", and $∂M$ has underlying set $\{ a, b \}$ but the orientation comes out to be +1 at $b$ and -1 at $a$.  Taking that orientation into account gives $∫_{∂M} F = -F(a) + F(b)$.

Comment: So $\partial\{a,b\} = -\{a\}+\{b\}$ because it's pointing outward and the positive direction is towards $b$?

Comment: @FrankVel Right.  One way I like to visualize this is to think of $[-1, 1]$ as a "slice" along the $x$-axis of the case where $M ⊂ R²$ is the unit disc - then $\partial M$ is the unit circle with orientation "going counterclockwise" which cuts the $x$-axis upward at (1, 0) and downward at (-1, 0).

Comment: @DanielSchepler, what do you mean that the orientation comes out at $+1$ at $b$ and $-1$ at $a$? Aren't points unoriented by definition?

Comment: @goblin The boundary of a 1-dimensional oriented manifold with boundary would be a 0-dimensional oriented manifold, which reduces to a set of points (necessarily with the discrete topology) with a sign assigned to each point.